# Unable to kill a process in shell script

Tags: shell-script, devilspie

I have this script:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd ~/.devilspie && devilspie Minimize.ds
pkill devilspie

exit 0
```

The first command runs absolutely fine, but in the second line where it needs to kill the process, it doesn't do so. If I run the command in terminal it works as intended but not in the script. Is there anything wrong with the script.

Comment: Run the script with `sh -x name`. Add the output to your posting.

Comment: Please run `devilspie Minimize.ds` and then add the output of `ps -ef | grep -i '[d]evil'` to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to run `devilspie` in background.  If you don't do this, the script will not reach the line with `pkill` until you terminate `devilspie` some other way.

You may start `devilspie` in the background by adding `&` to the end of the command:

```
cd ~/.devilspie && devilspie Minimize.ds &
```

Comment: @Kusalananda as I understood from comments below first answer, the script script doesn't get to the next line. It stops at devilspie. So that is why I suggested that running it in background mod could be the solution.

Comment: Adding an explanation to the answer (and not just "do this") helps them understand and learn.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these commands:

```
pkill -9 devilspie 
or 
pgrep devilspie | xargs kill -9 
or
killall devilspie
```

Comment: `pkill` and `kill` with `-9` but `killall` with the default `SIGTERM`...?

Comment: The script doesn't get to the next line. It stops at devilspie.